# How to make an event occur for only the first time that a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript

I have a series of events that I want to execute when a button is pressed. Among those, there is one event, `functionA();`, that I only want it to happen for the first time that the button is pressed (resets after each refresh). How can I do this? Thanks.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    functionA();
    functionB();
    functionC();
}
```

But I only want `functionA();` - `functionC();` to happen the first time the button is pressed. The second time onwards, only `functionB();`and `functionC();` will be executed. Is there a way to do this? This count should reset each time the webpage is refreshed too. Thanks

Comment: Add them separately and remove `functionB()` with `.removeEventListener("click", functionB)`, replace `functionB` with an empty function (`function functionB() { ... functionB = function() {}; }`), use a flag (global or a closure), ...

Comment: Additionally: If submit is an actual submit button in a form then a) rename it and b) use the form submit event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable to remember if it has already been done.

```js
let didFuncA = false;
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!didFuncA) {
    functionA();
    didFuncA = true;
  }
  functionB();
  functionC();
});

function functionA() {
  console.log("A");
}

function functionB() {
  console.log("B");
}

function functionC() {
  console.log("C");
}
```

```html
<button id="submit">Click</button>
```

FYI, these are just function calls, they're not events. `click` is an event.

Comment: Damn the solution was so simple, I am so silly, thanks so much :')

Comment: Hmmn although this should work, it isn't and functionA is still being executed after each click...

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for pointing out the difference between function calls and events too, noted

Answer (score 0):

If the button is an actual submit button and you are submitting a form that loads a page then

1. rename the button - never call anything submit in a form if you ever want to submit the form using script
2. use session or localStorage if the page is refreshed

I guess the page is NOT reloaded because I see a preventDefault, but in case you want to survive a page reload, use session or localStorage

If you meant to reset this after a page refresh, then of course do NOT use session/localStorage

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("submitted")) {
    functionA();
    sessionStorage.setItem("submitted","yes")
  }  
  functionB();
  functionC();
});
```

Comment: They said that the state should be reset when the page is reloaded, so it shouldn't use session storasge.